# Rasa roles of entities

Tags: python, nlp, wit.ai, rasa-nlu

My team is building a bot for hotel reservations and we have recently decided to migrate from Wit.ai to Rasa. In Wit.ai, we used the build-in entities:
 - `datetime` - with roles check-in and check-out
-  `number` - with roles number of people, number of rooms, and length of stay.

How can  I put roles to datetime and number entities in Rasa? I've seen entity roles are not supported: https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/issues/1169. Any ideas for a workaround? I guess I need something like double named-entity recognition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I too have the same question...